# Using methods as (curried) functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash, ramda.js

What is the most elegant way to convert a method to a curried function, and is there support for this in libs like Underscore/Lo-dash or Ramda?

For a fixed number of arguments I'm doing this right now:

```
var fn2 = _.curry(function (m, a1, a2, obj) {
  return obj[m].call(obj, a1, a2);
});
```

which allows for code like:

```
var a2b = fn2('replace', 'a', 'b')
a2b('abc')
=> 'bbc'
```

as well as:

```
var nl2_ = fn2('replace', '<br>')
nl2_('\n', 'some<br>html')
=> 'some\nhtml'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is; lo-dash obviously supports `curry`, what qualifies as "most elegant" beyond using it they way it's written?

Comment: curry only does half the job, it doesn't turn a method into a function

Comment: What precisely does that mean, "doesn't turn a method into a function"?

Comment: I want to turn object notation `obj.func(arg)` (where `func` is a "method" by virtue of being defined on and bound to the context of an object) into `func(arg, obj)` (a pure "function" which takes this context as an argument)

Comment: Ah, I understand now, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily extend your approach for methods with arbitrary arity:

```
function curryMethod(m, a) {
    if (a !== ~~a) a = m.length;
    return _.curry(function() {
        return m.apply(arguments[a], Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1));
    }, a+1);
}
```

```
> var replace = curryMethod(String.prototype.replace)
> replace("a", "b", "abc")
"bbc"
> var a2b = replace("a", "b")
> a2b("abc")
"bbc"
```

---

Since you also have asked about Ramda, I've only quickly scanned their API but found the [`R.invoker` function](http://ramdajs.com/R.html#invoker) which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Here is more info on the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: perfect, `R.invoker` must've slipped my eyes because of the similarity to `_.invoke` which does something quite different.